# Check duplicated keys in different go map types

Tags: go, generics

I want to have a function to check duplicated keys in different maps.

This is what I have

```
ma := map[string]typeA
mb := map[string]typeB
mc := map[string]typeC

dup := map[string]bool{}
    for k := range ma{
        if !dup[k] {
            dup[k] = true
        } else {
            return fmt.Errorf("duplicate key[%v]", k)
        }
    }
    for k := range mb{
        if !dup[k] {
            dup[k] = true
        } else {
            return fmt.Errorf("duplicate key[%v]", k)
        }
    }
    for k := range mc {
        if !dup[k] {
            dup[k] = true
        } else {
            return fmt.Errorf("duplicate key[%v]", k)
        }
    }
    return nil
```

I want to refactor this and I write a function

```
func checkDupKeys[M ~map[K]V, K comparable, V any](maps ...M) error {
    dup := map[K]bool{}
    for _, m := range maps {
        for k := range m {
            if !dup[k] {
                dup[k] = true
            } else {
                return fmt.Errorf("duplicate key[%v]", k)
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

But It can only accept maps with the same type, not typeA, typeB and typeC.

Comment: I'm afraid generics alone are not expressive enough to let you write such a flexible function.

Comment: You can do something with [maps.Keys](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/maps#Keys): `func checkDupKeys[K comparable](keys ...[]K) {}; checkDupKeys(maps.Keys(ma), maps.Keys(mb), maps.Keys(mc))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `any` type and reflection

```
func checkDupKeys(maps ...any) error {
    dup := map[any]bool{}
    for i, m := range maps {
        t := reflect.TypeOf(m)
        if t.Kind() != reflect.Map {
            return fmt.Errorf("not a map at index: %d", i)
        }
        keys := reflect.ValueOf(m).MapKeys()
        for _, k := range keys {
            v := k.Interface()
            if !dup[v] {
                dup[v] = true
            } else {
                return fmt.Errorf("duplicate key[%v]", v)
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Disadvantage of this approach is the fact that this function will also accept non-map arguments and compiler will not warn you about this.

Answer (score 1):

If I wanted to implement that function, I would chose a different approach

```
    package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    ma := map[string]int{"one": 1, "two": 2}
    mb := map[string]string{"one": "one"}
    mc := map[string]float64{"one": 1.1}
    fmt.Println(checkDupKeys(ma, mb, mc))

}
func checkDupKeys(maps ...any) error {
    dup := map[string]bool{}
    for _, m := range maps {
        v := reflect.ValueOf(m).MapKeys()
        for _, k := range v {
            if !dup[k.Interface().(string)] {
                dup[k.Interface().(string)] = true
            } else {
                return fmt.Errorf("duplicate key[%v]", k)
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/EroOjmY4nVt)